# How to extract features from tensorflow slim model VGG when doing forward run?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-slim, vgg-net

I have trained a model for classification using TensorFlow slim model vgg, using CASIA(a face recognition dataset) as training dataset.
I want to test the model by using LFW dataset, it is a face matching task. so I need to extract the net features like fc7/fc8, not the softmax layer, and compare the distance between the features, to determine whether they are the same person. 
How can I extract the features of a slim model?

Here is part of the training code.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.contrib.slim.python.slim.nets import vgg 
slim = tf.contrib.slim
FLAGS = tf.app.flags.FLAGS

def tower_loss(scope):
    images, labels = read_and_decode()
    with slim.arg_scope(vgg.vgg_arg_scope()):
        logits, end_points = vgg.vgg_16(images, num_classes=FLAGS.num_classes)
    _ = cal_loss(logits, labels)
    losses = tf.get_collection('losses', scope)
    total_loss = tf.add_n(losses, name='total_loss')
    return total_loss
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try using `tf.get_default_graph().get_tensor_by_name("VGG16/fc16:0")` or whatever tensor name of the specific feature you want to extract.

To verify the name of the tensors you are extracting, you can try

```
for operation in graph.get_operations():
    print operation.values()
```

Remember to put `:0` at the end of the names as they indicate the item you're retrieving is a tensor.

Answer (score 0):

Get `end_points` of slim model and extract the feature.